# Sintaxe da função Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, expressões-lambda

Estou bem no início do estudo da função Lambda e estou bem perdido. Sei que o código poderia ser feito apenas com a função "sum" mas quero aprender a sintaxe da Lambda.

```
a = []
for b in range(0, 4):
    c = int(input())
    a.append(c)
d = (lambda x, y: x + y, a)
print(d)
```

O programa tem que pegar quatro números digitados e mostrar a soma e acho que o erro está na linha 5. Como essa linha ficaria para somar todos os números armazenados na lista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lambda` em Python não é uma função. É uma palavra chave que permite definir uma função como uma expressão, ou parte de uma expressão. Quando você usa o lambda, dizemos que você criou uma nova função, e para encurtar chamamos a função *criada* usando o lambda de "função lambda"

No caso, a linha `d = (lambda x, y: x + y, a)` na verdade nem cria somente a função lambda - como a precedência da "," é menor que a do lambda (a vírgula é resolvida depois que o lambda já está definido), essa expressão na verdade cria uma tupla, em que o primeiro item será a função lambda `lambda x, y: x + y` e o segundo item será  `a`.

Mas, pelo que dá pra entender do seu programa, não é o `lambda` que te interessa - você quer aplicar a função que soma `x` e `y` a todos os elementos de `a` - o que faz isso é a função `reduce`.

A função `reduce` sim, recebe três parâmetros: Uma função no primeiro parâmetro, uma sequência no segundo, e um valor inicial no terceiro parâmetro. A função passada como primeiro parâmetro sempre vai receber dois argumentos: o primeiro que é o "resultado acumulado" e o segundo que é o "próximo item da sequência". Dessa forma, é muito comum se usar uma construção com lambda para criar a função que vai no primeiro parâmetro da chamada a reduce.

`TL;DR:` O que você quer nesse programa é isso:

```
from functools import reduce
...
d = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, a, 0)
```

O que isso faz? Como no caso em que você usou, a "," encerra o lambda - mas nesse caso, ela serve para separar o lambda do próximo argumento para a função `reduce`. E o `0` é o valor usado para o `x` na primeira chamada a função, que é chamada uma vez para cada elemento em `a`, que sempre será atribuído a `y`. As funções definidas com lambda não precisam de um `return`: o resultado da única expressão que elas contém já é seu valor de retorno - e o que o reduce faz é colocar esse valor como `x` na próxima chamada - até acabarem-se os elementos de "a" - o último valor que a função lambda retorna é retornado pelo `reduce`.

Pra ficar bem claro, perceba que usar `lambda` é exatamente a mesma coisa que criar uma função normal, com `def` e usar o nome dessa função onde se usa o `lambda`; Ou seja, esse código poderia também ser:

```
...
def soma2(x, y):
    return x + y

d = reduce(soma2, a, 0)
```

Resumindo: tanto reduce quanto lambda são conceitos que podem ser confusos se não está absolutamente claro para o programador. Se for o caso, é melhor evita-los e troca-los pelo código "por extenso" equivalente, que é bem mais simples de entender, em geral, tanto para quem escreve, quanto para quem lê. Há mais situações em que se usa o "lambda" no mundo real - as vezes precisamos de uma função para realmente fazer algo muito simples - seja criar um novo objeto do tipo lista quando se cria um "defaultdict" , ou um cálculo para o valor de chave numa ordenação quando se chama o "sorted".  Já `reduce` é algo mais restrito a trabalhos do tipo "map-reduce" - se for algo simples, vale a pena desdobrar em três linhas para legibilidade. Se for algo muito intensivo em cálculo, vale a pena usar uma biblioteca especializada em map-reduce, como o as ferramentas do hadoop ou o pandas.  Tanto que na transição para Python 3, o reduce deixou de ser um builtin e passou a ter que ser importado do módulo `functools`.

O reduce por extenso poderia ser algo como:

```
d = 0
for elemento in a:
   d = soma2(d, elemento)
```

mas perceba que para esse caso simples, você realmente não ganha muito com a chamada a função soma2 - pelo contrário, perde legibilidade. Então o mais normal vai ser vocẽ escrever:

```
d = 0
for elemento in a:
    d += elemento
```

Ainda há um pequeno ganho de performance por não se chamar uma função intermediária. A idéia do reduce é mais para linguagens com mais ênfase no paradigma de programação funcional (ou puramente funcionais), em que é mais normal precisar passar funções como parâmetros (algumas linguagens funcionais, no extremo, não tem sequer um equivalente ao `for` - você tem que usar funções como parâmetro de funções inclusive para emular um laço, como em haskell ou Scheme). São muito legais como exercício, e entender jeitos diferentes de abordar problemas, mas na prática requerem muito mais dispêndio de "energia mental" do que um simples laço interativo, como acima.

Tendo dito tudo isso: lambda, map, filter e reduce são uma pequena fração do que existe no paradigma "funcional" de programação. Python permite uma expressividade melhor que a do `map` e  `filter` usando as list comprehensions e generator expressions (ex.: `[x * 2 for x in range(10)]`) - mas o `reduce` só existe como função mesmo.  Se você quiser explorar mais esse paradigma, há um projeto muito legal em cima do Python, chamado "Coconut". Ele cria uma nova linguagem que é um superconjunto de Python (e na verdade, os arquivos de coconut são *compilados* para Python e executados com o runtime normal do Python). Coconut define dezenas de ferramentas e funções, além de uma sintaxe extendida, mais apropriados para programação funcional:

http://coconut-lang.org/

Comment: O zero no final faz alguma coisa?

Comment: sim - ele serve como valor inicial para o argumento "x".

Comment: Não estou conseguindo importar o intertools

Comment: Bom, você poderia ter mais sorte com `itertools` em vez de i*n*tertools - mas só um pouco mais de sorte. Por que o `reduce` está definido em `functools`, não no itertools