# Ordenando resultado

Tags: python, dicionário

Boa noite, preciso de ajuda para fazer uma ordenação de palavras desse código.

```py
texto = '''amar e viver, Amar é sonhar, sonhar é viver, viver é curtir, curtir é amar'''

def converte_texto(texto):
    pontuacao = ['.',',',':',';','!','?','"','(', ')']
    novo_texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in pontuacao).upper()
    lista = novo_texto.split()
    return lista

def palavras(texto):
    palavras = converte_texto(texto)
    contagem = dict()

    for palavra in palavras : 
        contagem[palavra] = contagem.get(palavra, 0) + 1

    return contagem

print(palavras(texto))
```

Esse é o resultado:

```
{'AMAR': 3, 'E': 1, 'VIVER': 3, 'É': 4, 'SONHAR': 2, 'CURTIR': 2}
```

Estou querendo que ele saia de forma ordenada decrescente, mais estou com dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ordenar um dicionário em Python é bem simples já que a linguagem conta com um método próprio para isso que funciona tanto com os dicionários, como listas e tuplas.

A sintaxe é `sorted(object, key, reverse)`, onde, no seu caso, `Object` é o próprio dicionário, `key` é a forma de organização e `reverse` é um booleano para dizer se você quer inverter a lista ou não. Ele é opcional e deixando em branco não vai inverter a resposta. O `key` também é opcional e se não for informado fará uma ordenação alfabética da suas chaves.

Como o seu caso necessita de ordenação por valores vamos precisar incrementar com mais uma função: `items()`.

Assim, é só acrescentar a seguinte linha no seu código e depois retornar essa variável mais abaixo. A função lambda aqui funciona como o ordenador e é, basicamente, uma função sem nome. Não vou explicar ela aquo, pq não é o escopo da pergunta, mas se quiser saber mais a respeito, [aqui tem uma boa explicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277188/sintaxe-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-lambda).

```
ordenado = sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
return ordenado
```

Note que como você quer uma ordenação do maior para o menor, eu dei o valor `true` para a variável `reverse`. No final seu código fica:

```
texto = '''amar e viver, Amar é sonhar, sonhar é viver, viver é curtir, curtir é amar'''

def converte_texto(texto):
  pontuacao = ['.',',',':',';','!','?','"','(', ')']
  novo_texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in pontuacao).upper()
  lista = novo_texto.split()
  return lista

def palavras(texto):
  palavras = converte_texto(texto)
  contagem = dict()

  for palavra in palavras : 
      contagem[palavra] = contagem.get(palavra, 0) + 1

  ordenado = sorted(contagem.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

  return ordenado

print(palavras(texto))
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar o método `sorted`, especificando a chave a utilizar na comparação. Neste caso:

```
def palavras(texto):
    palavras = converte_texto(texto)
    contagem = dict()

    for palavra in palavras : 
        contagem[palavra] = contagem.get(palavra, 0) + 1

    return return dict(sorted(contagem.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
{'É': 4, 'AMAR': 3, 'VIVER': 3, 'SONHAR': 2, 'CURTIR': 2, 'E': 1}
```